# How to check if docker using custom redis.conf file

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, redis, dockerfile

I am trying to add custom redis.conf file to bind 0.0.0.0 and connect my app with redis from another container.

My files:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\101\Desktop\Docker


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----          4/9/2022   6:12 PM                app
d-----          4/9/2022   6:41 AM                haproxy
-a----          4/9/2022   1:04 PM              5 .prettierignore
-a----         4/14/2022   5:57 AM            786 docker-compose.yml
-a----         4/14/2022   5:47 AM            117 Dockerfile
-a----         4/14/2022   5:13 AM          93759 redis.conf
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.8
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY app /home/node/app/
RUN npm install
CMD npm run app 
EXPOSE 9999 6379
```

docker-compse.yml

```
version : '3'

services:
    redis:
        image: redis
        container_name: redis
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
        command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
        volumes:
            - $PWD/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    lb:
        image: haproxy
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - ./haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy
    nodeapp1:
        container_name: nodeapp1
        image: nodeapp
        environment:
            - APPID=1111
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - lb
    nodeapp2:
        container_name: nodeapp2
        image: nodeapp
        environment:
            - APPID=2222
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - lb
```

I need to check if docker actually using the configuration file I provided.
How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can access to that container by using `docker exec -it <container-id | container-name> sh`, then you can check the configuration of redis by redis cli inside that shell